# Including two jsps in a parent jsp and placing them side by side

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, jspinclude

I am placing some issues in alignment of JSPs . I have a parent JSP that needs to iterate over a set of features and place them side by side with a "|" in between. The parent JSP I have written contains this

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="horizonte-amazon-tags" prefix="hza"%>
<%@ taglib uri="aui" prefix="a"%>

<c:forEach var="feature" items="${view.subfeatureMap['featureList'].subfeatures}">
    <c:set var="featureName" value="${feature.featureName}" />
    <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${featureName eq 'first'}">
                    <jsp:include page="../first/common.jsp" />
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${featureName eq 'second'}">
                    <jsp:include page="../second/common.jsp" />
            </c:when>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Now the first and second feature should come side by side with a separator "|" in between. I tried enclosing the two in separate divs like this using float.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="horizonte-amazon-tags" prefix="hza"%>
<%@ taglib uri="aui" prefix="a"%>

<c:forEach var="feature" items="${view.subfeatureMap['featureList'].subfeatures}">
    <c:set var="featureName" value="${feature.featureName}" />
    <c:choose>
            <div style="float:left">
            <c:when test="${featureName eq 'first'}">
                    <jsp:include page="../first/common.jsp" />
            </c:when>
            <div>
            <span class="byLinePipe">|</span>
            <div>
            <c:when test="${featureName eq 'second'}">
                    <jsp:include page="../second/common.jsp" />
            </c:when>
            <div>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

But this did not produce the output I want. This is placing the first and second feature one after the other Can someone point out where I am going wrong.

Comment: what is the output then ?

Comment: The output should be that first and second be placed side by side with a "|" in between.